Why are the Maximal Points Not Being Drawn
I'm working on project (admittedly for school) and having problems with a section of it, The parameters are:
A constructor that is supplied an array list of points that produces the initial point set and determines the maximal points and connects them
Implementing a private method that finds the maximal set and draws lines
/*The initial set of points being used:

200.0 300.0
250.0 300.0
330.0 270.0
150.0 380.0
126.0 172.0
397.0 379.0
334.0 441.0
53.0 288.0
89.0 433.0
182.0 215.0
251.0 414.0
*/  

public class PointPane extends Pane {
    
    private final ArrayList<Point> points;

    public PointPane(ArrayList<Point> points) {
        
        this.points = points;
        drawPoints();
        
        this.setOnMouseClicked(this::handleMouseClick);
    }

    private void drawPoints() {

        this.getChildren().clear();

        for (Point point : points) {
            
            javafx.scene.shape.Circle circle = 
                new javafx.scene.shape.Circle(
                point.getX(), point.getY(), 5);

            this.getChildren().add(circle);
        }

        findAndDrawMaximalSet();
    }

    private void findAndDrawMaximalSet() {

        ArrayList<Point> maximalSet = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Point point : points) {
            
            boolean isMaximal = true;

            for (Point other : points) {

                if (point != other && point.isBelowAndToLeftOf(other)) {
                    isMaximal = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isMaximal) {
                maximalSet.add(point);
            }
        }

        // this is where the error is, it never enters this if statement...

        if (maximalSet.size() >= 2) {
            
            Collections.sort(maximalSet);
            drawLines(maximalSet);
        }
    }

    private void drawLines(ArrayList<Point> maximalSet) {
        
        this.getChildren().removeIf(node -> node instanceof Line);
        
        if (maximalSet.size() >= 2) {
            
            for (int i = 0; i < maximalSet.size() - 1; i++) {
                
                Point p1 = maximalSet.get(i);
                Point p2 = maximalSet.get(i + 1);
                
                Line line = new Line(p1.getX(), p1.getY(), 
                p2.getX(), p2.getY());
                
                this.getChildren().add(line);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Point implements Comparable <Point> {
    
    private final double x;
    private final double y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX() { return x; }
    public double getY() { return y; }

    public boolean isBelowAndToLeftOf(Point other) {
        
        return this.y < other.getY() || 
            (this.y == other.getY() && this.x < other.getX());
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Point other) {
        return Double.compare(this.x, other.getX());
    }
}


Consider that javafx.geometry.Point2D "can also represent a relative magnitude vector's x, y magnitudes."

posted code is searching for only the first maximal point, so the Set will always have only one point (there is only ONE point [in the sample data] that is not "BelowAndToLeft" of the others)

According to your implementation of "maximal" point, only one point can be maximal. (If two points p1 and p2 are both maximal, then you must have p1.isBelowAndToTheLeftOf(p2)==false and p2.isBelowAndToTheLeftOf(p1)==false, otherwise at least one is not maximal. Then p1.y==p2.y, otherwise one of the previous method calls must evaluate to true, by the left hand side of the ||, and then p1.x==p2.x, by the right hand side of the ||.) So presumably your implementation of "maximal" is wrong, though you haven't stated what the definition is.

In the point.isBelowAndToLeftOf(other) there is a small problem: it doesn't properly check whether the point is maximal. I think it just checks if a point is below and to the left of another point. So all we need to do is to check if there are no other points above and to the right of the current point.
private void findAndDrawMaximalSet() {
    // this is your arraylist of points
    ArrayList<Point> maximalSet = new ArrayList<>();
    // I like to instantiate variables outside the loop
    boolean isMaximal = true;

    // looping though every point
    for (Point point : points) {
        // for very point check very other point
        for (Point other : points) {
            // i think we need to double check if the point is the same using this logic because you dont have a overridden equals method 
            if (point.compareTo(other) != 0 && point.isBelowAndToLeftOf(other)) {
                isMaximal = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isMaximal) {
            maximalSet.add(point);
            isMaximal = false;
        }
        
    }

    if (maximalSet.size() >= 2) {
        Collections.sort(maximalSet);
        drawLines(maximalSet);
    }
}

Side note I didn't see you importing the util package from java. Also you are using a lot of shortcuts which is fine but if the code gets too complex maybe just try to cut back the shortcuts and write it out. I understand that might be a newer version of java. But good luck I cant seem to see any other problems because I didn't have the plane class which you extended. (I was unable to compile all the code.)

Also make make sure that you only check point.isBelowAndToLeftOf(other) if there is more than one point

This is clearly wrong: it is impossible for more than one point to be maximal by this algorithm (the moment you find a maximal point, you set isMaximal to false, and, once the outer loop has started, there are no places in the code where you ever set it back to true).
